# Passing a context variable through a class in Django

Tags: html, django, django-views

how can i pass a context variable in a class. i know that i would use the `render` if i was showing my template from a function. and then i could just pass my context variable as part of the render. But how do i pass a context variable to html if i am using a class to show the template.

i have tried putting a function into my class but it has not worked.

**views.py**

```
class hithere(ListView):
model = Datadata
template_name = 'index.html'

def whatsup(request):
    context = {}
    context['my_string'] = "this is my sring"
    return render(request, context)
```

**Index.html**

```
<h1>  {{ my_string }} </h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the [**`.get_context_data(…)`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_context_data):

```
class hithere(ListView):
    model = Datadata
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['my_string'] = 'this is my string'
        return context
```

But perhaps more convenient is to define a method:

```
class hithere(ListView):
    model = Datadata
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def my_string(self):
        return 'this is my string'
```

and render this with:

```
{{ view.my_string }}
```

---

> **Note**: normally a Django models, just like all classes in Python are given a name in *PerlCase*, not *snake_case*, so it should be: `HitHereView` instead of <s>`hithere`</s>.

Comment: Thanks, i really appreciate it.